# How can I create a new post in blogdown with a .Rmd extension?

Tags: r, r-markdown, blogdown

I'm trying to create an R Markdown file using the function `blogdown::new_post("my new post")`, but it always creates a straight markdown file with a `.md` extension.

In the RStudio addin there is an option to change the format to either `.Rmd` or `.Rmarkdown` (https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/rstudio-ide.html#fig:new-post)

Is there any way to specify R Markdown format with the command line function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create R Markdown files with `blogdown` on the command line, I've found 2 different options:

1. With the function `blogdown::new_post()`, use the parameter `ext` e.g. `blogdown::new_post("my new post", ext=".Rmd")`
2. Set `.Rmd` or `.Rmarkdown` as the default extension by adding an option in the `.Rprofile` file e.g. `option(blogdown.ext = ".Rmd")` (Reload the R environment after updating.)

For further information on global options see: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/global-options.html

I didn't find any specific documentation on the function parameters, but entering the function name without the brackets in the terminal e.g. `blogdown::new_post` shows the function definition including different possible parameters:

```
function (title, kind = "", open = interactive(), author = getOption("blogdown.author"),
    categories = NULL, tags = NULL, date = Sys.Date(), time = getOption("blogdown.time",
        FALSE), file = NULL, slug = NULL, title_case = getOption("blogdown.title_case"),
    subdir = getOption("blogdown.subdir", "post"), ext = getOption("blogdown.ext",
        ".md"))
{
```